# Pandas: remove leading and trailing zero values from series

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove leading and trailing zeros from a pandas series, i.e. input like

```
my_series = pandas.Series([0,0,1,2,0,3,4,0,0])
```

should yield

```
pandas.Series([1,2,0,3,4])
```

as output.

I could do this recursively by removing the first (and last) zero and then calling the method again. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use numpys trim_zeros function.

```
import pandas
import numpy
my_series = pandas.Series([0,0,1,2,0,3,4,0,0])
numpy.trim_zeros(my_series)
```

Comment: how does one do the same thing quickly but for trimming `np.nan` values?